# In general, is it possible to construct a polynomial that is $w$-orthgonal to lower degree polynomials given any $w$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, orthogonality

**Background**

A function $q$ is $w$-orthogonal to a function $p$ if for a fixed $w \in C[a,b]$, we have

$$\int_{a}^{b} q(x)w(x)p(x)dx = 0$$

**Question**

Let $p$ be any polynomial of degree $n$ and $q$ be a polynomial of degree $n+1$, and suppose we have fixed a function $w$, what are the general methods through which we can obtain $q$ such that we are guaranteed $p$ and $q$ are $w$-orthogonal?

Comment: Assuming $w\geq0$ this defines an inner product on polynomials. You can then orthogonalize the basis $1,x,...,x^{n+1}$ by [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). By construction, the $n+1$st polynomial will be orthogonal to all lower degree ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You evaluate the integrals

$$I_d:=\int_{a}^{b} x^dw(x)p(x)dx.$$

Then take any solution of

$$\sum_{d=0}^{n+1}q_dI_d=0$$ where the $q_d$ are the coefficients of $q$.

Comment: This will work if (in the sense of giving you a polynomial $q$ of degree $n+1$) if and only if $I_{n+1}=0$, or $I_\ell \neq 0$ for some $1\leq\ell\leq n$.